# Posix thread arguments issue ( C )

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I'm running into a bit of trouble with C.  I'm a relatively new programmer and I'm trying to create a structure and pass it into two thread by reference.  I want one thread to put information into the structure and the other thread to add the information and print it out.  Pseudo-code of what I'm talking about is below:

```
typedef struct{ int x, y }addme;
main{
  addme argstopass;
  create_thread(method_store, (void*)&argstopass);
  create_thread(method_calc, (void*)&argstopass);
  //Code to tell store thread 'only' to run
  //Code to tell calc thread to run when store is finished.
  join_both_threads;
}

void method_store(void* args){
  addme info = *((addme*)args);
  info.a = 7;
  info.b = 3;
}  

void method_calc(void* args){
  addme info = *((addme*)args);
  print(info.a+info.b);
}
```

The issue is that when I try to add the information it's like the store method had never updated it.  The reference passed into the threads is the same, so I can't see why they wouldn't be able to access the same information as long as they both have a pointer to it.

Hopefully someone here can enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong.  If anything isn't clear, comment and I'll help to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addme info = *((addme*)args);
```

creates a locale variable on stack and copies content of `argstopass` into it.  Modifications happen on this local variable only and won't be seen by the second thread hence.

Use

```
addme *info = args;
info->a = 7;
```

and ditto for the second thread.  You will have to ensure that second thread waits with its printf() until first thread modified the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
void method_store(void* args){
  addme info = *((addme*)args);
  info.a = 7;
  info.b = 3;
}
```

This method creates a local copy of your structure field, updates that local copy, and then returns, destroying the copy and not doing anything to your main structure.